# ¿Por qué el src de un img toma la url actual más la ruta proporcionada? laravel 8

Tags: html, laravel, imagen, rutas, img

tengo una etiqueta img en html a la cual le mando un valor mediante blade de laravel de la siguiente manera:

```
<img class="img-fluid" id="imagen" src="{{ $datos->foto }}" width="250" alt="">
```

he utilizado este mismo código para mostrar la imagen en otra vista y todo va perfecto pero en una vista en concreto esto no sucede, la imagen no se muestra y lo que sucede es lo siguiente:

la url donde se genera el error es:

```
http://localhost/walijab/public/ajqijab/perfil/8
```

y para mostrar una imagen deberia concretarse la url:

```
http://localhost/walijab/public/storage/app/public/uploads/1630189654-profile.jpg
```

pero al encontrarme en la ruta del error; analizando el código desde la consola del navegador se logra ver que la ruta a la que se hace referencia el img es:

```
http://localhost/walijab/public/ajqijab/perfil/storage/app/public/uploads/1630189654-profile.jpg
```

que claramente es un error ya que esa ruta no existe. mientras que debería tomar la ruta raíz

```
 http://localhost/walijab/public/
```

y agregar allí el resto de la url que le mando mediante el

```
{{ $datos->foto }}
```

no estoy utilizando el {{ asset($datos->foto) }} ya que en la base de datos tengo esta ruta ya quemada, es decir $datos->foto ya devuelve

```
storage/app/public/uploads/1630189654-profile.jpg
```

así es como mando los $datos a la vista:

```
 public function verperfil($id){


$consulta = DB::select("select  * from users where id = $id and tipo = 2");


return view('ajqijab/perfil')->with('id', $id)->with('datos', $consulta); }
```

esta es la ruta que uso:

```
Route::get('/ajqijab/perfil/{id}', 'AjqijabController@verperfil');
```

y este es el error que he encontrado en la consola de google chrome:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué sucede esto? tiene algo que ver con las rutas de laravel? por qué razón toma la ruta actual en lugar de la ruta raiz antes de la direccion que le mando en el atributo src

Comment: Siento que a la pregunta le faltan detalles o código. Si puedes reformularla te podremos ayudar mejor.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar la parte del controlador, donde asignas a `$datos->foto`?

Comment: ahora edito la pregunta, muchas gracias

Comment: Pregunta actualizada cualquier ayuda la agradecería mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza la ruta absoluta con el helper de Laravel `asset()` en la etiqueta `img` de la plantilla blade y le pasas el valor de `$datos->foto`.

```
<img class="img-fluid" id="imagen" src="{{ asset($datos->foto) }}" width="250" alt="">
```

Esto te generará la ruta que quieres

```
http://localhost/walijab/public/storage/app/public/uploads/1630189654-profile.jpg
```

Espero esto pueda ayudarte

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, pero no utilizo la ruta absoluta ya que en la base de datos guardo la url de la siguiente forma: storage/app/public/uploads/1630189654-profile.jpg la ruta va quemada en la base de datos y eso lo he usado de esta manera en todos lados y siempre ha ido bien, mi pregunta es por que se toma la url actual en lugar de la raiz.

Comment: efectivamente encerrar $datos->foto en asset() es la solución, aúnque mi la ruta completa se ingresara asset() supongo hace validaciones extras que terminan acabando con el error aunque sigo sin entender por que solo en esta ruta me pide el asset() y en las demás no. muchisimas gracias.